# How can I create a select query to get employee name, total salary of employee, hobby name(comma-separated - use subquery for hobby name)?

Tags: mysql

Please refer below tables and fields.

```
Create an “employee” database and 4 tables (hobby, employee, employee_salary, employee_hobby).
hobby: id, name
employee: id, first_name, last_name, age, mobile_number, address
employee_salary: id, foreign key of employee, salary
employee_hobby: id, foreign key of the employee, foreign key of hobby
```

I execute this query as follows:

```
SELECT CONCAT(e.first_name, ' ', e.last_name) AS full_name, SUM(es.salary) AS total_salary,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(h.name)
    FROM hobby AS h
    INNER JOIN hobby ON h.id = eh.fk_hobby_id) AS hobby_name
FROM employee_hobby AS eh   
INNER JOIN employee AS e ON e.id = eh.fk_employee_id    
INNER JOIN employee_salary AS es ON es.fk_employee_id = eh.fk_employee_id
GROUP BY eh.fk_employee_id;
```

But I fetch all same hobby name in single row for particular record.
[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0clE6.png)

I need hobby_name for every record like sports,gaming or gaming,travelling etc.

Comment: Please share more details, like the table structure, sample input data, the expected output corresponding to that data, and your attempts to resolve the problem. What **exactly** is not working for the given query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not correct:

```
...
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(h.name)
    FROM hobby AS h
    INNER JOIN hobby ON h.id = eh.fk_hobby_id) AS hobby_name
FROM employee_hobby AS eh   
...
```

Just join `hobby` table in the query like other tables:

```
SELECT CONCAT(e.first_name, ' ', e.last_name) AS full_name, 
       SUM(es.salary) AS total_salary, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(h.name)
FROM employee_hobby AS eh 
INNER JOIN hobby h ON h.id = eh.fk_hobby_id
INNER JOIN employee AS e ON e.id = eh.fk_employee_id    
INNER JOIN employee_salary AS es ON es.fk_employee_id = eh.fk_employee_id
GROUP BY eh.fk_employee_id;
```

Comment: Thank you.
But I need to use a subquery for hobby name.

Comment: @JaivikPatel , you can [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70663061/edit) with more details if my suggestion doesn't work and we'll try to find a solution together. Please read Nico's comment.

Comment: Ohk sir.
If I have employee record in my employee table and I don't have any hobby and salary and etc. So, do uh help me to get only employee full_name with total_salary and hobby_name are blank??

Comment: Without seeing your data sample and expected output, I can't really tell but it sounds like you're looking to do `LEFT JOIN` instead. You can try to change the `INNER JOIN hobby` to `LEFT JOIN hobby` and see if it returns as what you expected.